# jQuery: If h1 has specific text then link should be added

Tags: jquery

This is my try so far:

```js
$("h1").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Google") {
    $(this).click(function() {
      window.open("https://google.com/");
    });
  }
});

$("h1").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Facebook") {
    $(this).click(function() {
      window.open("https://facebook.com/");
    });
  }
});

$("h1").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Instagram") {
    $(this).click(function() {
      window.open("https://instagram.com/");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Google</h1>
```

If the text of the `h1` is for Example `Google`, then the website link for the Google website should be added. If the text is `Facebook`, then the website link for the Facebook website should be added. It should update automatically if the `h1` changes.

My try does not work unfortunately, and it looks very laborious.

Has someone an idea how to do that in a smart way?

Thanksss <3

Comment: let say h1 is google. then when click it it should be redirect to https://google.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `window.ooen()` does not work in the SO snippet. That is why I have added the `console.log()` here for demo purposes.

```js
$("body").on("click","h1",function() {
  const url=$(this).text().toLowerCase();
  if(["google","facebook","instagram"].indexOf(url)>-1){
   console.log(`opening ${url}`); 
   window.open(`https://${url}.com/`);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Google</h1>
<h2>Google</h2> 
<h1>Instagram</h1>
```